# Simple file transfer

Tags: networking, file-sharing

Given two Linux boxes on a LAN, what's the simplest way to transfer files between them?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I use `scp`.

```
scp source desthost:/path/to/dest/.
```

to copy from the local machine to the remote machine, or

```
scp srchost:/path/to/file/file .
```

to copy from a remote machine to the local machine.

If the username is not the same on the remote machine,

```
scp user@srchost:/path/to/file/file .
```

Comment: I would add you can use  -r option with scp to recursively copy an entire directory

scp -r source desthost:/path/to/dest/

Comment: @Steve_ Good point.  Also -C will compress the files as they are being transferred, which can help over slow links.

Comment: It's either `scp` or `rsync` for me.

Answer (score 6):

I usually mount a directory through ssh via FUSE and sshfs.

Mount:

```
$ sshfs name@server:/path/to/dir /path/to/mount/point
```

Unmount:

```
$ fusermount -u /path/to/mount/point
```

Answer (score 6):

nfs could be useful.

The Network File System (NFS) allows a client node to perform   transparent file access over the network.  By using NFS, a client node operates on files residing on a variety of servers and server architectures, and across a variety of operating systems.  File access calls on the client (such as read requests) are converted to NFS protocol requests and sent to the server system over the network.

You might require help from your Unix Admin to setup it first time but its very useful.

Comment: For quick-n-dirty *nix-to-*nix transfers, nothing comes close to NFS.  A good admin can crank up both boxes and do transfers in less than 5 minutes, it's near-transparent to the rest of the system, and it's well-known and stable.  +1 for something that doesn't require banging out a command line every time to transfer something.

Answer (score 5):

I use netcat (if I don't need security)

```
nc -l -p 1234 < send_file   # 'server'
nc x.y.z.t 1234 > receive_file  # 'client'
```

Comment: I especially like this combo: `tar -c files and folders/ |pv -cN in|lzop|pv -cN out|nc x.y.z.t 1234`

Answer (score 3):

For one off file transfers, I usually use SFTP or an existing samba share.

For keeping in sync, I suggest you try [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) or [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/index.html) (for 2-way synchronization)

**Edit:** `scp` would be better then `sftp`, since it would work on all SSH enabled hosts

Answer (score 2):

For doing backups I often use rsync.  If I want to backup onto a remote machine I'll put a line in /etc/fstab to keep the remote machine mounted by NFS or CFIS (Samba).

```
192.168.0.101:/ /mnt/backup nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr 0 0
```

Then have a line in my crontab using rsync.

```
rsync -av /home/user/sourcedir/ /mnt/backup/destinationdir > /home/user/backup.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Giver is a simple file sharing desktop application. Other people running Giver on your network are automatically discovered and you can send files to them by simply dragging the files to their photo or icon shown in Giver.

In Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install giver
```

Answer (score 1):

netcat is simple but not all versions close connection reliably.

Here is thread about using `socat`:
[socat reliable file transfer over TCP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22308/socat-reliable-file-transfer-over-tcp)

To sum it up:

[Proposed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22308/9689):

> Server sending file:
>
> ```
> server$ socat -u FILE:test.dat TCP-LISTEN:9876,reuseaddr
> client$ socat -u TCP:127.0.0.1:9876 OPEN:out.dat,creat
> ```
>
> Server receiving file:
>
> ```
> server$ socat -u TCP-LISTEN:9876,reuseaddr OPEN:out.txt,creat && cat out.txt
> client$ socat -u FILE:test.txt TCP:127.0.0.1:9876
> ```

[Proposed enhancements](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23682/9689):

> - `OPEN:out.txt,creat,trunc` will delete all the bytes in `out.txt` before writing to it.  This option mimics what you'd expect from `cp`,
>     and is probably what you want.
> - `OPEN:out.txt,creat,excl` will refuse to write `out.txt` if it already exists.  Use this option for extra safety.
> - `OPEN:out.txt,creat,append` will append data to `out.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use [Giver](http://code.google.com/p/giver/) program. Using it you could transfer files over LAN with 2 clicks or by "drag'n'dropping" file to recipient. Recipients (which also have to run `giver`) are discovered via Zeroconf, so you don't have to know even their IP. Here's [video on how Giver works](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=3768442676796881783).

Comment: As somebody who's worked on Giver in the past, I can say it's a neat app, but it's totally unmaintained and has plenty of bugs, especially when it comes to transferring large files.  Don't expect much from it.

Comment: @Sandy yes, I'm aware of bugs. In my case, 1.4G files were transferred successfully. Anyway, using Giver still looks much easier than NFS/rsync/nc/whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have an account (password) on the receiving host you can use woos (web offer one stream):

woos file-or-directory ...

http://fex.belwue.de/fstools/woos.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good answers here, and some mention Giver and how it has trouble with large files. A very similar tool which handles large files seamlessly and gzips the transfer is [portal](https://github.com/ZinoKader/portal).

(**NOTE**: I wrote this!)

#### How to use it

**Alice** wants to send `<folder1>` and `<file.txt>` to **Bob**, who can be behind the same NAT for direct transfer or anywhere on the internet for relayed transfer. Portal will use direct transfer if it's possible.

##### Alice initializes the file transfer by executing the following in her shell

`$ portal send <folder1> <file.txt>`

This outputs a temporary password, which Alice communicates to Bob via some other secure channel.

```
# the output of the send command, use this password to receive the files 
> 1-supernova-gamma-ray
```

##### Bob executes the following command to receive `folder1` and `file.txt`

`$ portal receive 1-supernova-gamma-ray`

The file transfer will now begin!

**Pros**

- e2e encryption
- fast gzip (de)compression
- simple protocol aids transfer speed
- handles folders of any sort and depth
- direct communication if ports are open or behind same NAT

**Cons**

- does not do NAT traversal so transfer goes through a relay if direct communication cannot be established
- it's a new tool so it is untried in different systems and might have weird bugs

Comment: That's a good point, as it's not at all obvios from my comment. Added!

Comment: Is "Generate password" seriously just a short list of some words?

Comment: Yes, the password is created from a list of words along with a unique number prefixed, three words along with the prefix create a full password. The password exists only until the connection has been established. Similar tools also work like this. It is a trade-off for being able to communicate the password easily over any channel, such as a voice chat or in-person. The actual communication once established is then fully encrypted.