# Downloading and uploading files via telnet session

Tags: linux, ssh, file-copy, telnet, file-transfer

I have an attendance device running `Linux OS`. I can connect this device via telnet session. There are some files in the device that I would like to download and upload with new files. How can I do that? I have very low knowledge on Linux OS. Would you please help!

[image]

Comment: How many files do you want to transfer? Can you paste somewhere output of `busybox --help` and `ls  -l /bin` and `ls -l /usr/bin`, please.

Comment: actually I wanna change desktop background of this attendance device, and want to upload our company logo there in the device. Such options is not available in device menu (I already asked for this option to vendor). So I connected it via telnet session and found desktop.jpg and other image files in the device. Now I want to get these file on My local system. and after verifying the same I will upload my desirable images in the device. So it will update device image according to my desirable images. I want to change at least desktop image which is available in the device at /mnt/mtdblock/image

Comment: If you want to add information the next time, please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/171456/edit) your question instead of adding comments.

Answer (score 20):

This depends which tools are installed on the client device / supported by the kernel.

Possible methods for file transfer (unordered):

- ssh / sftp
- encoding binary files into displayable format with base64/uuencode and then copy from/into your telnet terminal window.
- over a simple tcp connection with `netcat` or `socat` or with `bash` and /dev/tcp
- upload / download with `wget` or `curl` from a web server
- ftp server with a command line ftp client
- samba or nfs mount

Read [Simple file transfer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272/simple-file-transfer) and [How to get file to a host when all you have is a serial console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312/how-to-get-file-to-a-host-when-all-you-have-is-a-serial-console) for more possibilites.

---

#### Copy `desktop.jpg` from the device to your pc with the netcat/nc method:

On your pc, disable temporarily (or reconfigure if possible) any firewall and
run

```
netcat -l -p 10000 > desktop.jpg
```

and on the device

```
busybox nc A.B.C.D -p 10000 < desktop.jpg
```

where you need to replace A.B.C.D with the IP address of your pc.
As soon as the transfer was successful, the netcat process on your pc should stop automatically. If not, something could have gone wrong and you can stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (compare source and destination checksums to verify).

For the other direction, just exchange `<` and `>` on both sides. Make first a backup of the original `desktop.jpg` (`cp desktop.jpg desktop_orig.jpg`).

Comment: I tried WinSCP utility and tried to connect the device using ftp/sftp/scp protocol. but it is not getting connected. I am able to connect the device via telnet command and able to see the files that I want to get and upload again into device.

Comment: Probably your device does not have a ssh or ftp server running.

Comment: Well I don't know that.. Is there any other way to get/upload files from that device?

Comment: You can also use `sz` to send the files through the terminal. You'll need it on both sides.

Comment: @PRdeepKumawat I extended the answer with an example.

Comment: On the device side, I had to remove `-p` from the command line for it to work: `busybox nc A.B.C.D 10000 < desktop.jpg`.

Comment: useful on pmos.

Comment: Why `busybox` command should be placed before `nc`? Without `busybox` I'm getting connection refused...

Answer (score 9):

I have no ssh or ftp(or etc) on the device.

So, I do next:

1. `telnet a.b.c.d | tee telnet.log`
2. login and go to the file
3. `cat file.txt`
4. close session (I close tmux pane)
5. clear `telnet.log` from trash

It should be easy to write utility to download/upload file over telnet

Answer (score 3):

I just uploaded a ~7 Kb firmware file to a BusyBox based Linux embedded system over the serial port.

**No networking, no file transfer utilities; no Base64 utils or anything remotely useful on the device.**

On the host, I trivially encoded a firmware into the following format; a kind of hex-dump consisting of shell literals combined with `printf` commands:

```
printf "\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF\x...\xF0"
printf "\xCA\xFE\x33\xE1\x...\xD3"
```

basically shell `printf` commands with `\x` escape sequences that `printf` interprets. On the device I did:

```
device $ cat > firmware.sh
```

then used the `minicom`'s ASCII file send (<kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) to send this file to the host. I could just have used copy and paste, since the amount of data is small.

Then, marked executable and ran the `printf` script:

```
device $ chmod a+x firmware.sh
device $ ./firmware.sh > firmware.bin
```

Checked using BusyBox's `md5sum` that the `firmware.bin` checksum on the device matches the original firmware image on the host.

P.S. The shell double quote syntax passes through `\x` verbatim because it's not a recognized escape sequence; hence we don't have to double up the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `rcp` command.

Use `man rcp` for more information in case you want to automate transfers.

By the way, you do know this is **very insecure**, right?

Answer (score 1):

On your PC:

`ncat -l -p 3000 > file.name`

On remote device:

`busybox nc -w 3 <your PC IP> 3000 < file.name`

Answer (score 0):

@jofel and all others, Thank you very much for your kind assistance. I think device has a customized os installed as it recognized some specific linux commands only. netcat is not recognized by the device. However today I got success to transfer the file using tftp command. I successfully replaced desktop.jpg file with this command. What I did is, created tftp server on window system. login via telnet on device and run these commands:

download file
tftp -l  -p  
tftp -l desktop.jpg - 192.168.0.249 69

upload file
tftp -l desktop.jpg -g 192.168.0.249 69

Answer (score 0):

I have done this now by these methods:

Create ftp server (by installing solerwinds) on window system. login via telnet on device and run these commands:

To download a file:

```
tftp -l <FileName> -p <TFTP Server IP> <Port No of TFTP>
```

Example:

```
tftp -l desktop.jpg -p 192.168.0.249 69
```

or to upload file:

```
tftp -l <FileName> -g <TFTP Server IP> <Port No of TFTP>
```

Example:

```
tftp -l desktop.jpg -g 192.168.0.249 69
```

default location of tftp file is `C:\TFTP-Root`

Answer (score -1):

I use the following method to download small binary files via telnet into my windows box:

1. execute hexdump -v -e '16/1 "%02x"' myfile.bin
2. copy hex dump from screen
3. paste hex dump into this online tool to create binary file: http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_file.php?lang=en

Comment: Not sure about your link in #3!

Comment: @Goro The link in this case is not an explanation that can be quoted, it is an online tool that is essential for the answer. It would be better to have a local program for that task.

Comment: Thanks @RalfFriedl.  I edited my answer for clarification.